# How to pin Google Chrome with a specific user (profile) to Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar

I am running Google Chrome v71 with two profiles. How do I pin it to the taskbar with both, specific profiles?

Answer (score 30):

1. Go to the Chrome settings
2. Go to "Change name and picture" in the People section[image]
3. Toggle "Show desktop shortcut"[image]
4. In case you already pinned your default Chrome to the taskbar you need to unpin it
5. Find the created shortcut on your desktop and pull it onto your start bar or right click and select "Pin to taskbar"
6. Repeat with other account

Comment: Also, you can reverse step 3 once pinned and the pinned version will stay keeping your desktop clean. Thanks @tossilo-posegga !

Comment: incidentally, this toggle only appears once more than one account is defined, breaking UI best practices established for decades.

Comment: Can confirm this still works on Windows 11. :)

Answer (score 10):

From 2016 to today (2019-01) this has changed and previous solutions no longer work. I've only found this tedious process that works for me:

1. Pin any running Chrome profile window to the taskbar.
2. In the Windows Explorer app, open `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
3. Open Chrome's app properties (Shift+right-click -> Properties), extend the target with `--profile-directory="Default"`
4. Change `"Default"` into the corresponding folder name from `%userprofile%\appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`, e.g. `"Profile 1"`
5. For more than one pinned Chromes, copy this file and adapt

Comment: Note: %userprofile%\appdata\Local = %localappdata%

Comment: I used this route in the 2019 timeframe. But now with Windows 10 I had to use the other method (going through Chrome settings to create a desktop shorcut)

Comment: **Note:** the `User Pinned` folder is hidden

Answer (score 4):

It's 2022 and I had this issue with Win11. To add shortcuts for different chrome profiles to the taskbar, do the following:

1. Open Chrome and login
2. Go to Settings -> You and Google -> Customize your Chrome profile
3. Enable 'Create desktop shortcut'
4. Right-click the desktop shortcut and click 'Show more options'
5. Click 'Pin to taskbar'

Repeat for other profiles. You can remove the desktop shortcuts afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

2023.11.19: Using Windows 11 Home, the settings that result from steps 1-5 given by Diego above were already set and my desired Chrome profile icon was not pinned to the taskbar (two others were). I closed my browser windows that used the desired profile, did step 4 and then did the opposite of step 5, clicking 'Unpin from Taskbar', then redid step 5, clicking 'Pin to taskbar.' Now my desired Chrome profile's icon shows on the taskbar.

Comment: And now it doesn't show "Pint to taskbar" anymore...